# Highcharts 3D funnel Array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

I'm following [the instructions](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/funnel3d) of feeding the funnel with array data,

supposedly in the documentation, it should be:

```
data: [

  ['Website visits', 15654],
  ['Downloads', 4064],
  ['Requested price list', 1987],
  ['Invoice sent', 976],
  ['Finalized', 846]
]
```

this is how I get the array:

```
let url = 'url.com/api...';
fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {
  console.log(out.Data);
  var forFunnel = out.Data

  //highchart demo sample code

}).catch(err => { throw err });
```

my array data is:

```
{ Value: 228230938.61, Stage: "Prospect" }
{ Value: 30000000, Stage: "Prospect1" }
{ Value: 29267484.58, Stage: "Prospect2" }
{ Value: 21414898.46, Stage: "Prospect3" }
```

Is there a type of conversion am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the returned `Data` to the appropriate format (here using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)):

```
var forFunnel = out.Data.map(({ Value, Stage }) => [Stage, Value]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to do something like: var data = [];
            for (var i in Data) {
                var serie = new Array(Data[i].Stage, Data[i].Value);
                data.push(serie);
            }

Comment: Well I'm glad you got it working. The method you described is a basic implementation of map() ;)